# How can Selenium see a record that I can't find from a debugger?

Tags: django, unit-testing, selenium

I am creating Selenium tests for my App.
I can create a new user, but I can't seem to figure out how to have it deleted from the database.

After the tests run successfully the first time, subsequent tests fail because the username already exists.

**Why am I not able to query the newly created record in the debugger despite being able to see the new record on the page?**

**How do I delete a record from the database in a test?**

This is what I have been doing:

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from django.utils import unittest  
from forum.models import Question, Answer, User  

class TestOSQAAuthentication(unittest.TestCase):  
    scheme = 'http'  
    host = 'localhost'  
    port = '4444'  

    def setUp(self):  
        self._driver = webdriver.Firefox()  
        self._driver.implicitly_wait(25)  


    def test_anon_can_create_new_account_manually(self):  
        self._driver.get('http://localhost:8000/account/local/register/')  
        self._driver.find_element_by_id('id_username').send_keys('MrManual')  
        self._driver.find_element_by_id('id_email').send_keys('test@gmail.com')  
        self._driver.find_element_by_id('id_password1').send_keys('test')  
        self._driver.find_element_by_id('id_password2').send_keys('test')  
        self._driver.find_element_by_id('bnewaccount').click()   
        # verify MrManual was created  
        self._driver.get('http://localhost:8000/users/')  
        self._driver.find_element_by_link_text('MrManual')  
        # MrManual seems to be created, but I don't see MrManual in the database during debugging with:  
        # import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()  
        #ipdb> User.objects.all()  
        #[<User: Bryan>, <User: Kallie>, <User: Stalin>]  
        # here I am trying to delete the user from the database directly.
        User.objects.filter(username="MrManual").delete()  
        """For some reason I can't delete the record from the database from the test.  
        Selenium can find the new user in the browser, but I can't query the database to find it."""
```

Comment: Hmm to verify that a User entry is indeed created in the database, perhaps you can try something like `self.assertTrue(User.objects.filter(username="MrManual"))`?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Selenium, instead of `django.utils.unittest.TestCase` please use `django.test.TransactionalTestCase` or even better, `LiveServerTestCase`.